# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS using authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error when I use the authorization to deny anonymous users in my app.

I read quite similar questions on Stack Overflow but I can't solve my problem.

I'm using the `/Account/Login.aspx` predefined by asp.net

I only added this to Web.config file into `<system.web>`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name="Login" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Shall I post more other code?

Comment: Can you share the exact exception.

Comment: Do you have add the `~/Account/Login.aspx` to exception and leave it open to anonymous ?

Comment: Now yes, thank you

Comment: Now I get access denied from the server, i suppose this is something about the iis config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the IIS, I just chanched the pool to .Net traditional.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in web.config

```
<configuration>
    <location path="Account/login.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Your login.aspx is also not accessible to anonymous users. This configuration should fix it.

Comment: Now I get access denied from the server, i suppose this is something about the iis config